# Варианты морфем

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, чередования

Корзинка — корзинок. Суффиксы "К" и "ОК" — являются ли они вариантами морфем (чередованием) или это просто новое слово, образованное с помощью суффикса?

Answer (score 2):

**Корзин/а — корзин/к/а, нет корзино/к.**

Здесь суффикс К с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением. При склонении слова **в основе перед суффиксом К** появляется беглая гласная  О.

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен с версией Sharon:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В слове *корзинка* суффикс *-**к**(а),* как пишет Шанский в "Очерках по русскому словообразованию", не уменьшительно-ласкательный, а

> суффикс чисто стилистического характера, меняющий лишь стилистическую
>   окраску слова (слово *корзинка* — разговорное, слово *корзина* —
>   межстилевое), но не его лексическое значение (ср. *большая корзина* —
>   *большая корзинка*).

В форме родительного падежа имеет место фонетический вариант суффикса ***-к-***: корзин-**ок**-□.

Формальное различие между морфами объясняется их позицией в слове: суффиксальный морф *-к-* выступает перед флексиями, начинающимися гласными фонемами, а морф *-ок-* — перед нулевой флексией.

Ср. с разбором слова *марочка* в пособии В.Н. Мусатова "Русский язык: морфемика, морфонология, словообразование":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]